# Should $watch work if I change variable on $broadcast

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I broadcast undo-redo-changed event from my service and handle in scope.on but $watch funciton don't called. Why? Is it correct way to use $watch? The porpose of these code to change button state when drawModule service propery variable is changed. 
My code is

```
   $scope.$on('undo-redo-changed', function () {        
    $scope.canUndo = drawModule.canUndo() ? '' : 'disabled';
    $scope.canRedo = drawModule.canRedo() ? '' : 'disabled';        
}); 

$scope.$watch('canUndo', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.canUndo = newValue;
}, true);

$scope.$watch('canRedo', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.canRedo = newValue;
}, true);
```

Comment: Why are you $watching and then just setting it to the new value? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I am trying to disable button by changing $scope.canUndo and $scope.canRedo properties. But if i change them in $on it don't work. So I added $watch. But $watch not called.

Answer (score 0):

`$watch` parameters are reversed it is current value and old value.

Use:

```
$scope.$watch('canUndo', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.canUndo = newValue;
}, true);
```

also if `canUndo` is simple value you don't need to set third parameter of `$watch` to true (it is used to watch array and nested structures).